# Why does findFirst() throw a NullPointerException if the first element it finds is null?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

Why does this throw a `java.lang.NullPointerException`?

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
strings.add(null);
strings.add("test");

String firstString = strings.stream()
        .findFirst()      // Exception thrown here
        .orElse("StringWhenListIsEmpty");
        //.orElse(null);  // Changing the `orElse()` to avoid ambiguity
```

The first item in `strings` is `null`, which is a perfectly acceptable value. Furthermore, `findFirst()` returns an [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), which makes even more sense for `findFirst()` to be able to handle `null`s.

EDIT: updated the `orElse()` to be less ambiguous.

Comment: null isn't perfectly acceptable value... use "" instead

Comment: @MicheleLacorte although I'm using `String` here, what if it's a list that represents a column in the DB? The value of the first row for that column can be `null`.

Comment: Yes but in java null isn't acceptable..use query to set null into db

Comment: @MicheleLacorte, `null` is a perfectly acceptable value in Java, generally speaking.  In particular, it is a valid element for an `ArrayList<String>`.  Like any other value, however, there are limitations on what can be done with it.  "Don't ever use `null`" is not useful advice, as you cannot avoid it.

Comment: @NathanHughes - I suspect that by the time you call `findFirst()`, there's nothing else you want to do.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The reason for this is the use of `Optional<T>` in the return. Optional is not allowed to contain `null`. Essentially, it offers no way of distinguishing situations "it's not there" and "it's there, but it is set to `null`".

That's why [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) explicitly prohibits the situation when `null` is selected in `findFirst()`:

> **Throws:**
>
> `NullPointerException` - if the element selected is `null`

Comment: It would be simple to track if a value does exist with a private boolean inside instances of `Optional`. Anyway, I think I'm bordering ranting - if the language doesn't support it, it doesn't support it.

Comment: Also, I would be happy if you have any alternatives (was hoping for a functional programming-like solution). Time to convert it to a for loop.

Comment: @neverendingqs Absolutely, using a `boolean` to differentiate these two situations would make perfect sense. To me, it looks like the use of `Optional<T>` here was a questionable choice.

Comment: @neverendingqs I can't think of any nice-looking alternative to this, besides [*rolling your own null*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern), which isn't ideal either.

Comment: I ended up writing a private method that gets the iterator from any `Iterable` type, checks `hasNext()`, and returns the appropriate value.

Comment: I think it makes more sense if `findFirst` returns an empty Optional value in PO's case

Answer (score 76):

As [already discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32466863/2711488), the API designers do not assume that the developer wants to treat `null` values and absent values the same way.

If you still want to do that, you may do it explicitly by applying the sequence

```
.map(Optional::ofNullable).findFirst().flatMap(Function.identity())
```

to the stream. The result will be an empty optional in both cases, if there is no first element or if the first element is `null`. So in your case, you may use

```
String firstString = strings.stream()
    .map(Optional::ofNullable).findFirst().flatMap(Function.identity())
    .orElse(null);
```

to get a `null` value if the first element is either absent or `null`.

If you want to distinguish between these cases, you may simply omit the `flatMap` step:

```
Optional<String> firstString = strings.stream()
    .map(Optional::ofNullable).findFirst().orElse(null);
System.out.println(firstString==null? "no such element":
                   firstString.orElse("first element is null"));
```

This is not much different to your updated question. You just have to replace `"no such element"` with `"StringWhenListIsEmpty"` and `"first element is null"` with `null`. But if you don’t like conditionals, you can achieve it also like:

```
String firstString = strings.stream()
    .map(Optional::ofNullable).findFirst()
    .orElseGet(()->Optional.of("StringWhenListIsEmpty"))
    .orElse(null);
```

Now, `firstString` will be `null` if an element exists but is `null` and it will be `"StringWhenListIsEmpty"` when no element exists.

Comment: Sorry I realized that my question might have implied I wanted to return `null` for either 1) the first element is `null` or 2) no elements exist inside the list. I have updated the question to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: In the 3rd code snippet, an `Optional` may be assigned to `null`. Since `Optional` is supposed to be a "value type", it should never be null. And an Optional should never be compared by `==`. The code may fail in Java 10 :) or when-ever value type is introduced to Java.

Comment: @bayou.io: [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/doc-files/ValueBased.html) doesn’t say that *references* to value types can’t be `null` and while *instances* should never be compared by `==`, the reference may be tested for `null` using `==` as that’s the *only* way to test it for `null`. I can’t see how such a transition to “never `null`” should work for existing code as even the default value for all instance variables and array elements is `null`. The snippet surely is not the best code but neither is the task of treating `null`s as present values.

Comment: see [john rose](https://blogs.oracle.com/jrose/entry/value_types_in_the_vm) - *nor can it be compared with the “==” operator, not even with a null*

Comment: anyways, this is their plan, that `Optional` will not be used like "normal" reference types. so that in future, it can be transitioned to "value type". But people will definitely "misuse" it; the warning on javadoc is certainly very inadequate.

Comment: Since this code is using a Generic API, this is what the concept calls a *boxed* representation which can be `null`. However, since such a hypothetical language change would cause the compiler to issue an error here (not break the code silently), I can live with the fact, that it would possibly have to be adapted for Java 10. I suppose, the `Stream` API will look quite different then as well…

Comment: Add 3rd code snippet, I see `Optional.empty` as a result of `.stream().map(Optional::ofNullable).findFirst().orElse(null)` (**not** `null`) - in case the first element in stream is `null`.

Comment: What's the purpose of `skip(0)` here?

Comment: @RayJasson good question. I suppose, it’s a leftover from some testing that slipped through. Should have no effect. I removed it.

Answer (score 41):

You can use `java.util.Objects.nonNull` to filter the list before find

something like

```
list.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst();
```

Comment: I want `firstString` to be `null` if the first item in `strings` is `null`.

Comment: unfortunately it uses ```Optional.of``` which is not null safe. You could ```map``` to ```Optional.ofNullable ``` and then use ```findFirst``` but you will end up with an Optional of Optional

Answer (score 19):

The following code replaces `findFirst()` with `limit(1)` and replaces `orElse()` with `reduce()`:

```
String firstString = strings.
   stream().
   limit(1).
   reduce("StringWhenListIsEmpty", (first, second) -> second);
```

`limit()` allows only 1 element to reach `reduce`.  The `BinaryOperator` passed to `reduce` returns that 1 element or else `"StringWhenListIsEmpty"` if no elements reach the `reduce`.

The beauty of this solution is that `Optional` isn't allocated and the `BinaryOperator` lambda isn't going to allocate anything.

Answer (score 1):

Optional is supposed to be a "value" type. (read the fine print in [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html):) JVM could even replace all `Optional<Foo>` with just `Foo`, removing all boxing and unboxing costs. A `null` Foo means an empty `Optional<Foo>`.

It is a possible design to allow Optional with null value, without adding a boolean flag - just add a sentinel object. (could even use `this` as sentinel; see Throwable.cause)

The decision that Optional cannot wrap null is not based on runtime cost. This was a hugely contended issue and you need to dig the mailing lists. The decision is not convincing to everybody.

In any case, since Optional cannot wrap null value, it pushes us in a corner in cases like `findFirst`. They must have reasoned that null values are very rare (it was even considered that Stream should bar null values), therefore it is more convenient to throw exception on null values instead of on empty streams.

A workaround is to box `null`, e.g.

```
class Box<T>
    static Box<T> of(T value){ .. }

Optional<Box<String>> first = stream.map(Box::of).findFirst();
```

(They say the solution to every OOP problem is to introduce another type :)

Comment: There is no need to create another `Box` type. The `Optional` type itself can serve this purpose. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32476601/2711488) for an example.

Comment: @Holger - yes, but that might be confusing since it's not the intended purpose of Optional. In OP's case, `null` is a valid value like any other, no special treatment for it. (until sometime later:)

Answer (score 0):

First,Java's stream operations such as map and filter do not actually execute until a terminal operation such as findFirst() is called. When findFirst() is called, the stream framework starts executing the entire chain of operations.

So, It can be find in the source code.
This is the core method:
[image],the function is mentioned in annotation.
Next,it will step into [image] in FindOps.

**wrapAndCopyInto(S sink, Spliterator<p_in> spliterator)**
Applies the pipeline stage described by the current PipelineHelper to the supplied Spliterator and sends the result to the supplied Sink

Then it will start to process the stream.
[image]
This is used to push the elements obtained from the Spliterator into the provided receiver Sink. performs a Sink#cancelationRequestedl) after each element and terminates if the return request is true. This method, when implemented, adheres to the Sink protocol, i.e., Sink#begin->Sink#accept->Sink->end.
Now,we can see the accept method in FindSink
[image]
**If the value is null, hasValue will be true,but this.value will be null**

Now we can return to **evaluateSequential**,we will get a **Sink**,which hasValue = true and value = null.
Then when you call the get method, it will call Optional.of(value).
[image]
Optional cant accept a null value,so it will throw a NPE

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).