# java 8 findFirst vs map on optional

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-8, java-stream, option-type

Given this code:

```
class Foo {
  Integer attr;
  public Integer getAttr() {return attr;}
}

List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Foo());

list.stream().map(Foo::getAttr).findAny().orElse(null);  //A
list.stream().findAny().map(Foo::getAttr).orElse(null);  //B
```

Line A throws

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null

while line B returns null.

What is the cause of this behaviour? Both `findAny()` and `map()` return `Optional<T>`.

Comment: See also [Why does findFirst() throw a NullPointerException if the first element it finds is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32466799/2711488)

Answer (score 7):

```
list.stream().map(Foo::getAttr).findAny().orElse(null);
```

[Java doc for streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) says that Stream: "returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given function to the elements of this stream", and findAny() "could return aNullPointerException - if the element selected is null". In your class Foo, Integer(not int) by default is set to null because is declared but not initialized. see [Primitives see default values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and [Object initialization in Java](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076614/core-java/object-initialization-in-java.html)

Initialization is different for:
A) Class Members (Objects and primitives)
B) Local Variables

Comment: You should edit your answer adding your source for that ;) I know them but this is better

Answer (score 5):

First, your two code snippet `map` are different operations:

```
//            v--- stream intermediate operation
list.stream().map(Foo::getAttr).findAny().orElse(null);  //A
//                      v---- a Optional utility method 
list.stream().findAny().map(Foo::getAttr).orElse(null);  //B
```

and the `NullPointerException` occurs in [Stream#findAny](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--) operation, since it can't accept a `null` value. due to it uses [Optional.of](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#of-T-) rather than [Optional.ofNullable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-). and the documentation of [Stream#findAny](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--) is already asserts:

> **Throws**:
>
> `NullPointerException` - if the element selected is **null**

so if you want your `A` code snippet works fine you must filter all `null` values before calling [Stream#findAny](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--), for example:

```
//when no elements in stream, `findAny` will be return a empty by Optional.empty()
//                                                       v   
list.stream().map(Foo::getAttr).filter(Objects::nonNull).findAny().orElse(null);//A
```

Comment: Well done! I thought nobody was going to talk about `filter(Objects::nonNull)`

Answer (score 4):

Well it's obviously because of the order in which you perform these operations and also because `findAny` explicitly says : `throws NullPointerException if the element selected is null`

When you do `map(Foo::getAttr)` you have effectively mapped that to `null`, so your Stream now contains a `null`; thus `findAny` breaks with an Exception (since `findAny` is applied on that null)

The other operation first finds the `Foo` object, then maps it to `Foo::getAttr` (thus mapping it to `Optional.empty()`), thus `orElse` is called.

Also, this would make more sense (for me at least):

```
 list.stream()
     .findAny()
     .flatMap(f -> Optional.ofNullable(f.getAttr()))
     .orElse(null);
```

`flatMap` would map to `Optional<Integer>` (attributes), in case this one is `empty` get the `orElse` result.

Comment: Ahem, it is impossible to have an `Optional` mapping to `null`. An `Optional` is either, empty or mapping to a non-`null` value. The OP’s second case, calling `map(Foo::getAttr)` on an optional, does exactly the same as your `flatMap(f -> Optional.ofNullable(f.getAttr()))`. In either case, the result is an empty optional and the argument passed to `orElse` is returned. (and saying “`orElse` is not called” makes no sense anyway. There is no way how the invocation of `orElse` could be skipped)

Comment: @Holger gosh that was stupid from my side, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
list.stream().map(Foo::getAttr)
```

... returns a stream with one element, with a value of null.

The JavaDoc for `findAny()` (and `findFirst()`) says:

> **Returns:**
>
> an Optional describing some element of this stream, or an
>   empty Optional if the stream is empty
>
> **Throws:**
>
> NullPointerException - if the element selected is null

So `findAny()` is doing exactly as documented: it's selecting a null, and as a result, throwing `NullPointerException`.

This makes sense because `Optional` is (again according to JavaDoc, but emphasis mine):

> A container object which may or may not contain a **non-null** value

... which means you can guarantee that `Optional.ifPresent( x -> x.method())` will never throw `NullPointerException` due to `x` being null.

So `findAny()` could not return `Optional.of(null)`. And `Optional.empty()` means that the stream was empty, not that it found a null.

Many parts of the `Stream`/`Optional` infrastructure are about discouraging the use of nulls.

You can get around this by mapping the nulls to `Optionals`, to yield an `Optional<Optional<Foo>>` -- which looks a bit convoluted, but is an accurate representation of your domain. `Optional.empty()` means the stream was empty. `Optional.of(Optional.empty())` means it found one null element:

```
list.stream().map(Foo::getAttr).map(Optional::ofNullable).findAny()
```

Comment: using a `flatMap` would make it cleaner: `list.stream().findAny().flatMap(f -> Optional.ofNullable(f.getAttr())).orElse(null);` like I wrote above...

Comment: @Eugene If you want to get nulls out of it, yes. In my mind though, this code can be a boundary between a domain where nulls can exist, and a domain in which everything is guaranteed non-null.