# Java 8 - Sort list of integers with nulls

Tags: sorting, null, java-8

Lets say you have a list of integers containing null vaues

```
List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(null, 9, 11, 7, 5, null);
```

Now if you want to get max value, you can try

```
OptionalInt max = integers.stream()
        .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
        .max();
```

This would work if the list did not contain nulls. In our case there will be a NullPointerException. After some research I can see such solution

```
Optional<Integer> max = integers.stream()
        .max(Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

It works if you consider nulls less then non-nulls. But if you want them to be greater and change nullsFirst to nullsLast

```
Optional<Integer> max = integers.stream()
        .max(Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

then you will meet NullPointerException again.

I am interesting  - why nullsLast doesn't work in this case considering that its doc states that it is null-friendly?
And what is the best way to sort list of Integers containing nulls?

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Consider changing the name of this question. It has nothing to do with sorting, has it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of [`Stream#max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) states:

> Throws: NullPointerException - if the maximum element is null

As you provided a comparator that will consider `null` as a maximum element, then that is why it throws the exception.

This is what the stacktrace indicates when it tries to return `Optional.of(state);` with `state` being `null` in your example, and `Optional.of` throws a NPE if the value being passed is `null`.

`Comparator.nullsLast` works fine, for example:

```
Integer max = 
    Collections.max(integers, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

will indeed give you `null`.

Answer (score 4):

That's not about `Comparator` per-se:

```
List<Integer> result = integers.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(result); // [5, 7, 9, 11, null, null]
```

You are putting your nulls to the end and that would be `max`; calling `max` on a null throws that `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 2):

If you consider `null` to be larger than any non-`null` value, the maximum will be, of course, `null` when list contains any `null`.

Since [`Stream.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) already documents that it will throw a `NullPointerException` when the result is `null`, this is expected behavior. The design rationale is similar to `findFirst()`, which has been discussed in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32466799/2711488).

Note that even

```
Optional<Integer> max = integers.stream()
    .max(Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

can still fail, i.e. if all values are `null`. But there is no point in using a custom `Comparator` here, as the solution is straight-forward:

```
OptionalInt max = integers.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
    .max();
```

When you get an empty `OptionalInt`, you may still test `integers.isEmpty()` to determine whether all elements were `null` or there were no elements at all.