# Java streams findAny() encounters null pointer exception after filter() operation filters out everything

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am having trouble figuring why `findAny()` throws a null pointer exception after `filter()` operation on a stream. In this particular test case, the filter operation should have filtered out everything, leaving no results for `findAny()`.

```
Optional<JsonNode> encryption = sseEncryptionList.stream()
                  .filter(n -> n.textValue().equals("AES256")) //Filters out everything
                  .findAny(); //Throws null pointer exception
```

The stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at example.Main.lambda$main$0(Main.java:41)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:174)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1351)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findAny(ReferencePipeline.java:469)
at example.Main.main(Main.java:42)
```

Is this expected behavior for `findAny()` to throw a null pointer exception if the stream doesn't contain any elements?

Edit: What is an elegant and functional way to resolve filter operations that might filter out all elements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does findFirst() throw a NullPointerException if the first element it finds is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466799/why-does-findfirst-throw-a-nullpointerexception-if-the-first-element-it-finds)

Comment: well if you want to filter nulls, just use `filter(Objects::nonNull)` as I said in the answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The best way to avoid NPE is:

```
Optional<JsonNode> encryption = sseEncryptionList.stream()
              .filter(Objects::nonNull)
              .filter(n -> "AES256".equals(n.textValue()))
              .findAny();
```

`"AES256".equals(n.textValue()))` will not throw NPE if n.textValue() is null

Answer (score 6):

Your confusion comes from the fact that you `filter` first - and you would expect the `filter` method to be somewhere in the stack trace; but notice that intermediate operations do nothing per-se, they are executed lazily and only kick in when a terminal operation is present (such as `findAny` in your case). It's actually *there* in the stack trace (the `filter method`), but it looks like this: `Example.Main.lambda$main$0(Main.java:41)`.

If you want to filter null values, first do:

```
.filter(Objects::nonNull)
.filter(n -> n.textValue().equals("AES256"))
.findAny()
```

Comment: Actually filter'ing lambda is in the stack trace (`at example.Main.lambda$main$0(Main.java:41)`) - so the exception is thrown there. `findAny` just happens to be the outermost function in the trace.

Comment: @Cthulhu thx, that's what I meant. hard to change a diaper and answer SO :) will edit...

Comment: What happens when n.textValue() return null?

Comment: @YegorBabarykin take a guess what happens when you call a method on an null reference :)

Comment: I mean then `filter(Objects::nonNull)` is required, but next line can throw NPE when `n.textValue()` return `null`

Comment: @YegorBabarykin you are correct, you could simply invert the equals in such a case: `n -> "AES256".equals(n.textValue())`

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not the behavior, when the stream doesn't contain any elements. In which case it instead returns an `Optional.empty()`.

Also, the NPE is the cause of a null value in the stream, as stated in the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--):

> ```
> Returns:
> an Optional describing some element of this stream, or an empty Optional if the stream is empty
>
> Throws:
> NullPointerException - if the element selected is null
> ```