# Java Stream : Nested Stream lookup Over Multiple List throws NPE

Tags: java, list, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have the following code in Java 7:

```
List<Integer> idMappers= new ArrayList<>();

//getting information from a Map<String, List<String>>
List<String> ids= idDataStore.lookupId(id); 

 for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++) {

 //getting information from a Map<String, List<Integer>>
  List<Integer> mappers= idDataStore.lookupMappers(ids.get(i));

  if (mappers!= null) {
    for (int j = 0; j < x.size(); j++) {
      idMappers.add(mappers.get(j));
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to change this to Streams

```
List<Integer> idMappers= new ArrayList<>();
idDataStore.lookupIdMappings(id).forEach(id-> {
  idDataStore.lookupSegments(id).forEach(mapper->{
    idSegments.add(segment);
  });
});
```

My problem is `idDataStore.lookupSegments(id)` can sometimes throw null so my stream is breaking. How Can I do a null check in Stream?

Comment: try this one `idDataStore.lookupIdMappings(id)
            .stream()
            .map(i -> idDataStore.lookupSegments(id))
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .forEach(s -> s.forEach(idSegments::add));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the variable (`id`) using in lambda cannot have the same name as the variable in the very same scope of the method.

> Lambda expression's parameter id cannot redeclare another local variable defined in an enclosing scope.

I see you work with nested for looping, why to not use the `Stream::flatMap`?

```
idDataStore.lookupIdMappings(id).stream()
                                .map(i -> idDataStore.lookupSegments(id))
                                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                .flatMap(List::stream)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `idDataStore.lookupSegments(id).stream().filter(Objects::notNull)` to you nested loop.

However what you have is a [side effect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)(see side effect section) and it is not recommended way to populate `idMappers` list. Let me try to convert using `flatMap`

```
List<Integer> idMappers = idDataStore.lookupIdMappings(id)
           .stream() // stream of LookupId's
           .flatMap(idMapping -> idDataStore
                                .lookupSegments(id)
                                .stream()
                                .filter(Objects::notNull)
                                // get stream of corresponding lookupSegments
                                // and filter out all nulls
           )
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47082894/1450401 but didn't help throwing the same error