# Why Java Streams min method does not accept null values, even if the used comparator is null-friendly?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I am trying to calculate the minimum between some values using lambdas. These values may contain nulls which is normal for my business case, as they represent interval limits. For example if I have the next intervals `(null, 10], (10, 15], [20, null)` - I want to check which is the lowest interval boundary between values `(null, 10, 20)` and I expect `null` to be the result (as null should be considered the equivalent of –infinity as a business case rule).

I tried implementing this with streams but I noticed that the min method from the Stream class cannot be used for such a scenario.

```
private Integer lowestIntervalLimit(Integer... intervalsLowerLimits) {
    return Arrays.stream(intervalsStart)
            .min(nullsFirst(Integer::compareTo))
            .orElse(null);
}
```

The reason is described in the min method Javadoc “Throws: NullPointerException - if the minimum element is null”. I tried a workaround and used reduce instead of min but I have the exact same issue:

```
private Integer lowestIntervalLimit(Integer... intervalsLowerLimits) {
    return Arrays.stream(intervalsStart)
            .reduce(BinaryOperator.minBy(nullsFirst(Integer::compareTo)))
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Am I missing something here or is this an API limitation and I should stick to fors and ifs?

Comment: As an idea, could you `map` the collection first and set any `null` values to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, and then continue?

Comment: You could just sort intervals rather than lower bounds, or use Integer.MIN_VALUE, or use Optional<Integer>, or wrap the Integer into a Bound object. min() returns an Optional<Integer>. An Optional can't hold a null value. And if it returned an empty Optional, the result would be ambiguous: does it mean there is no min value, or that the min value is null?

Comment: JB Nizet is right, the API is like this due to the ambiguous situation between empty lists (no min value) and cases when the min value is null. Sorry, it’s late in this time zone, I should have seen that :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not being able to return a `null` result, is connected to the `Optional`, see also, “[Why does findFirst() throw a NullPointerException if the first element it finds is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32466799/2711488)”.

Since your input is a plain array, there is no reason to worry about iterating it twice, e.g.

```
private Integer lowestIntervalLimit(Integer... intervalsLowerLimits) {
    return Arrays.stream(intervalsLowerLimits).anyMatch(Objects::isNull)? null:
        Arrays.stream(intervalsLowerLimits).min(Comparator.naturalOrder()).orElse(null);
}
```

But if that’s a concern, you could just use a loop

```
private Integer lowestIntervalLimit(Integer... intervalsLowerLimits) {
    Integer i = null;
    for(Integer j: intervalsLowerLimits)
        if(j == null) return null; else if(i==null || j<i) i = j;
    return i;
}
```

Comment: I can't tell what has been asked more, special null handling or order in streams... good answer, yet again!