# How to return just one string from java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I understand how to collect to a `List`, but can't figure
how I would return just one parameter of filtered object as a `String`.

```
fee = new BigDecimal(fees
            .stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getTodate().isAfter(LocalDateTime.now()))
            .filter(p -> p.getFromdate().isBefore(LocalDateTime.now()))
            .filter(p -> p.getId().equals(id))

    return fee;
```

I first check that the fee is up to date, as there might be upcoming fees and fees that are no longer valid. Then I match the id with remaining fees.
But then there is code missing between last filter and return.

I just want to return `String` from `Stream` object (p.getFee) for `BigDecimal` constructor.

I know there is only one `Stream` object remaining after filters.

Comment: If you expect a single element or 0 element in the collected stream you should explicit handle the case as you have more than 1 element from the collect.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `findFirst` to return the first element of the `Stream` that passes your filters. It returns an `Optional`, so you can use `orElse()` to set a default value in case the `Stream` is empty.

```
fee = new BigDecimal(fees
            .stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getTodate().isAfter(LocalDateTime.now()))
            .filter(p -> p.getFromdate().isBefore(LocalDateTime.now()))
            .filter(p -> p.getId().equals(id))
            .map(p -> p.getFee())
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(/*some default value*/));
```

Comment: Or perhaps throw an exception, if it is an exceptional state.

Comment: do you happen to know why .filter(p -> p.getInstrumentid().equals(id)) part cant find match even tho i looked it up and data definitely contains fee object with given id? if i take the last filter out, everything else works..

Comment: @Clomez what's the type of id and the return type of getInstrumentId?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it would be a better approach:

```
fee = fees.stream()
        .filter(p -> p.getTodate().isAfter(LocalDateTime.now()))
        .filter(p -> p.getFromdate().isBefore(LocalDateTime.now()))
        .filter(p -> p.getId().equals(id))
        .map(p -> p.getFee())
        .findFirst()
        .map(BigDecimal::new)
        .orElse(/*some default value*/);
```

Comment: You can also change the first `map` operation to `.map(p -> new BigDecimal(p.getFee()))`

Comment: but in this case, you could pass null to "new BigDecimal(null)"

Comment: In which scenario? When `getFee()` returns `null`, your variant will fail with a `NullPointerException` too.

Comment: i don't think(but not sure) because if p.getFee()==null then it go orElse

Comment: Recommended read: [Why does findFirst() throw a NullPointerException if the first element it finds is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32466799/2711488)