# null and NullPointerexception in Java stream

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-stream

Here is my example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;


public class Example {

     public static void main( String[] args )  {

         ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
         list.add(0);list.add(1);list.add(2);

         SomeObject  a = IntStream.range(0,list.size())
                  .filter(i->list.get(i)==3 || list.get(i)==4)
                  .mapToObj(i->new SomeObject(i,list.get(i)))
                  .findFirst()
                  .orElse(null);
         System.out.println(a);
   }
}

class SomeObject{
    int index;
    int value;
    SomeObject(int index,int value){
            this.index=index;
            this.value=value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.index+" "+this.value;
    }
}
```

Why when we are calling `System.out.println(a);` we don't get a NullPointerException?

As the orElse(null) returns an object pointing to null. If not what is the difference between the null in the orElse method and an object pointing to null?

Comment: `System.out.println` can print a `null` reference.

Comment: why it is not the case for an optional pointing to null. for that i was confused.if i put .get(); in place of orElse(null), i will get an exception.

Comment: for that sake `SomeObject b =null;
        System.out.println(b);` would not throw an NPE either. Strongly believe that this is a duplicate. Voting to close as duplicate. There are answer stating, what causes NPE as well in the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go a little bit in detail...

`System.out.println(a);` calls this overload of `println`:

```
public void println(Object x)
```

which states:

> Prints an Object and then terminate the line. This method calls at
>   first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value, then
>   behaves as though it invokes print(String) and then println().

Given the above let's go to the `String.valueOf` method:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj)
```

which states:

> Returns: if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null";
>   otherwise, the value of obj.toString() is returned.

Since `obj` is *null* a "null" is returned and `obj.toString()` is never invoked hence no exception.

---

As for your following comment:

> why it is not the case for an optional pointing to null. for that i
>   was confused.if i put .get(); in place of orElse(null), i will get an
>   exception.

an `Optional<T>` doesn't "point to null" (wrong terminology being used, usually we say an Optional either has a *present* state or *absent* state).

Invoking `.get()` carelessly from an `Optional<T>` should be avoided unless absolutely sure the `Optional<T>` is not empty.

You receive a `NoSuchElementException` in this case simply because there is no value present and this is documented in the `Optional<T>` API.

Answer (score 1):

> why it is not the case for an optional pointing to null.

To answer this comment as I think this is what you are trying to ask in the question, see this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32466863/4701158)

An optional, introduced in Java 8, is a container object which is used to **contain specifically, not-null objects.** Instead, optional object is used to represent null with absent value.

The fact that the findFirst() method returns Optional is a questionable design decision. But that's just how it is currently.